# SQL Conditional UPDATE Based on SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-update

In SQL Server 2008, I have a set of data containing costs for East and West. I'm adding a new field for a customer for Canada which needs to be 1.5 times the East or West cost (which ever is greater). So I'm trying to come up with some sql I can execute. I've tried the following but have not had success:

```
 UPDATE ShippingCost

 SET

    IF EastCost>WestCost

       Canada= EastCost*1.8

    ELSE

       Canada= WestCost*1.8
    ENDIF
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please specify what database platform you're working with?

Comment: Using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Your spec says, "1.5 times the East or West cost (which ever is greater)" i.e. factor is 1.5 but your code uses the factor 1.8.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use Case

```
 UPDATE ShippingCost

 SET
     Canada = CASE WHEN EastCost>WestCost THEN  EastCost*1.8
                   ELSE WestCost*1.8 END
```

Comment: Excellent! Works exactly the way I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use two update statements:

```
UPDATE SHIPPINGCOST SET Canada = EastCost*1.8 WHERE EastCost>WestCost
UPDATE SHIPPINGCOST SET Canada = WestCost*1.8 WHERE EastCost<=WestCost
```

Comment: Performance.  If the table is large then the optimizer might not be smart enough to exploit an index if you use the CASE statement.  Also, not sure how portable the CASE clause is.  I know it wasn't supported in some older Oracle versions (you had to use DECODE).  It's ANSI standard now, but you still have to make sure it works in the version of the DB you are running.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE ShippingCost SET Canada = GREATEST(EastCoast, WestCoast) * 1.8;
```

**Note:** T-SQL dialect does not support `GREATEST`.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle have `GREATEST` but I can't think of any Dialect that does `Max(a,b)`

Comment: Yes, it's not `MAX` but `GREATEST`. Sorry for the mistake! `MAX` is another function that doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ShippingCost
   SET Canada = 1.5 * CASE 
                         WHEN EastCost > WestCost THEN EastCost
                         ELSE WestCost
                      END;
```